# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter show lyrics on a lock screen

Tags: objective-c, ios5, mpnowplayinginfocenter

Music App shows lyrics(page of text) on a lock screen.

I tried to set MPMediaItemPropertyLyrics to show a lot of text, but it doesn't.
Any ideas?

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter* mpic = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
            mpic.nowPlayingInfo = @{MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle:sight.guide.name,
        MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:sight.name, MPMediaItemPropertyLyrics:sight.note};
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set lyrics.

Only some types of properties shown in following document can be set:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Does this mean that you cannot display the lyrics on the lock screen?

Comment: @Neeku No, you can't. If you really want to show lyrics on the lock screen, you may have to make an image which contains lyrics text and set it on MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork property.